# How to grab data from array /list in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

the information below is saved in $data and I want to fetch the value of "number of wins" in one line and the "tier" in the next? How can I achieve that not using syntax similar to the first two lines below:

```
// $tier =$data->{20720131}->tier
// $wins = $data->{20720131}[0]->entries[wins]

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents(###));

returns this when i echo it 

  {"20720131": [{
  "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
  "name": "Taric`s Zealots",
  "entries": [{
     "leaguePoints": 0,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": false,
     "division": "V",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": false,
     "playerOrTeamName": "MikeDog",
     "playerOrTeamId": "20720131",
     "wins": 4
  }],
  "tier": "SILVER"
 }]}';
```

Comment: use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @castis that would result in requiring the first two lines of the code. No clue why he wouldn't want that, as that is the actual data format, but it's his question.

Comment: I guess its because he's not always going to know what that number is. I posted my go at it below :/

Comment: i use $data = json_decode(file_get_contents(###);

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming you wish not to do this because you're unsure of what that number will always be.

So, you could do this.

```
$data = '{"20720131": [{
  "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
  "name": "Taric`s Zealots",
  "entries": [{
     "leaguePoints": 0,
     "isFreshBlood": false,
     "isHotStreak": false,
     "division": "V",
     "isInactive": false,
     "isVeteran": false,
     "playerOrTeamName": "MikeDog",
     "playerOrTeamId": "20720131",
     "wins": 4
  }],
  "tier": "SILVER"
 }]}';

$data = (array) json_decode($data);
$data = current(current($data));

var_dump($data->tier);
```

Comment: $data is in the format of a JSON string. PHP has built in support to convert JSON strings into a PHP Array. This is an ideal solution if you are going to be using at least more than two pieces of data in your PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 5.4, you can do this:

```
$wins = json_decode($data, true)['20720131'][0]['tier'];
$tier = json_decode($data, true)['20720131'][0]['entries'][0]['wins'];
```

Just in 2 lines as you requested.

Better way, and more compatible, would be:

```
$data_array = json_decode($data, true);
$wins = $data_array['20720131'][0]['tier'];
$tier = $data_array['20720131'][0]['entries'][0]['wins'];
```

But that's 3 lines.

Comment: This is good if wins and tier is all the data you need or want.

Comment: `json_decode($data);` means create object from `$data`. and when you pass the parameter `true`, it means create array from `$data`

Comment: this gives me a blank screen so here is an error it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

It could also be done using a regular expression. Which I do not recommend.

```
preg_match_all("/wins\": ([0-9]*)\n.*\n.*tier\": \"([A-Z]*)/i", $data, $output);
$wins = $output[1];
$tier = $output[2];
```